# Split a git-repository and merge it later on

Tags: git, merge

At this point I've a `1.0`-version of my repository. Since it's finished, I'ld like to start working on `1.1`. Every version will be pushed to the server after it's finished. However, when a version contains bugs (spelling mistakes for example) that would be `1.0.1`. Since I already started working on `1.1`, I'm not able to edit `1.0` anymore.

One solution would be to duplicate the repository (so you get `1.0` *and* `1.1`) and then minor bugs in `1.0` and push that version. However, when I do that and I want to launch `1.1`, it'll still contain the same bugs as `1.0` did before `1.0.1`.

I'm looking for a solution where I can split (fork?) the repository, add changes to it, and when it's ready, merge it again with the main repository:

```
   /------------------------- 1.1 ------------------------- \
  /                                                          \
 /          /------- 1.0.1 ---------\                         \
/          /                         \                         \
--------- 1.0 (main) -------- 1.0.1 (main) ---------------- 1.1 (main) -------
```

Where `1.1` also contain the bug fixes I made in `1.0.1`.

I hope this is possible. If so, could you give me the full `git`-commands I need to use and the terminalogy / naming conventions (so I know where to search for when I encounter some more problems).

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Read this. It speaks to exactly what you're trying to accomplish.

http://nvie.com/posts/a-successful-git-branching-model/

Now, it assumes you're aware that in git, branching is a top-level, frequent operation. It's easy to make branches, merge them back into other branches, rename them, get rid of them, etc, etc.

Comment: Thank you very much. Those images are great for starting learning the idea =)! I'm using a GUI (Gity) now, so that I can 'practice' with the names and terminology =). Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2):

What you are looking for are `branch`es.

A git branch is an independent tree inside a git repository. For more information have a look at the documentation: http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-branch.html

Answer (score 1):

Another good source is this article "[Branching Strategies in Git – Overview](http://gitguru.com/2009/02/18/branching-strategies-overview/)" (less complex than the current standard **[git-flow](http://jeffkreeftmeijer.com/2010/why-arent-you-using-git-flow/)**)

Extract, and git command examples:

> **For a single developer**, you can work on an experimental code path:
> You’ve got an idea about how a feature should be implemented and want to get started.
> But you’ve also got some regular development that needs to take place at the same time (fixes, other features, etc.).
> So **create a branch** and code away:

```
$ git branch feature_x dev
$ git checkout feature_x
# add/commit... add/commit... add/commit
```

[image: Feature branch created off dev branch]

> (Feature branch created off dev branch)
>
> If the feature code works out, you merge it back into your development branch.

```
$ git checkout dev
$ git merge feature_x
```

[image: Feature branch merged into dev branch]

> (Feature branch merged into dev branch)
>
> If not, you just go back to the dev branch and delete feature_x:

```
$ git checkout dev
$ git branch -D feature_x
```

[image: Feature branch left unmerged]

> (Feature branch left unmerged)
>
> Actually, you really don’t have to delete the branch.  You can leave it as is in case you want to easily go back to take a look at that work.